# not able to load Multiple data source in datagridview using dataset?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, textbox, datasource

I have a Windows forms application where I have to load different fee structures tables for different courses in one datagridview using the textbox but I do not know how to use the multiple datasources for datagridview.
I have 20 fee structure which differ from each of them by the values in it 
I have a Textbox where i would retrieve the name of the table to be retrieved but how should I proceed further ?

I used the have made a DataSet named fSDataSet where all the datatables are stored 
Now I want to load the tables when I get the values from the form

```
private void fSDataSetBindingSource_CurrentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        BindingSource bindingsource = new BindingSource();
        string getfeest = "FYBIOTECH";
        string s = @"Data Source=SRINATH-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=FS;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False";
        SqlConnection OK = new SqlConnection(s);
        SqlDataAdapter getfeestructure = new SqlDataAdapter();
        SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(getfeestructure);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"Select * from " + getfeest, OK);
        getfeestructure.SelectCommand = cmd;




        DataTable dt = new DataTable(@"fsDataSet." + getfeest);
        dt.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        getfeestructure.Fill(dt);
        bindingsource.DataSource = dt;
        dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(
        DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCellsExceptHeader);


    }
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fSDataSetBindingSource_CurrentChanged(sender, e);
    }
```

Now the error it is not displaying the rows
and I am not able to understand the actual error.

Answer (score 0):

Set 
    datagrid1.Datasource= fSDataSet.    Tables[0];
here Tables[0]indicates 1st table in datasouce...you can set the datasorce to the table depending on course

Comment: Cannot find table 0.
I have tables in it But how to assign them their number !!